# Count the Number of Documents in a LVWP on a WP Page WITHOUT without Totaling

Tags: list-view-threshold, pages, list-view-web-part

I have a Document Library list view web part (LVWP) on my SPO Page.

Because of the 5,000 item threshold, I had to disable any counts under the 'Totals' menu in the list view editor. However, I would like to know the total amount of documents/items displayed in the LVWP.

Is there some code or script that can be pasted into a script editor wp in order to achieve this?

Comment: You want to display a count of items that are currently displayed in the WebPart, or you want to display the total count of items in the source list?

Comment: Currently displayed is the priority, but if possible, I'd like to include BOTH the current displayed total as well as the total count of items in the source list

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using a classic-mode page in SharePoint Online?  You haven't explicitly tagged your post with which version of SharePoint you are using, but you mention "SPO Page" which implies you are in O365, and if you are truly using a List View Web Part, that is only available in classic-mode (although there is a modern List Web Part that behaves similarly and is often confused with the original).

Comment: Sharepoint Online (NON-PREM), classic view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are referring to SP on-prem environment here or SPO, assuming we are using Classic SharePoint features here, the following concept is going to work for both the environment.

For classic page, place a script editor webpart on the page where you have List View WP added and paste the following code.

In SharePoint REST API we have the list/library end point to list total number of documents in it.
`<path to site collection or web>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<List Title>')/ItemCount`

Here is the complete code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="listItemCount"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var listTitle = "<Title of list goes here>";
        var siteURL = "https://<URL to Web where list is available>";

        var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/ItemCount";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            $("#listItemCount").text(data.value);
        }, function(error){
            // Code for error handling
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!